# Send email on connection lost between WebSphere and MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-7, message-driven-bean

My configuration

- MDB using activation specs on WAS 7
- Default MQ Resource adapter config

Time to time, the connection is lost between the WAS and MQ and the MDB shuts down. Is there an easy way to send emails when it happens other than by activating the tracing on the resource adapter and defining a smtp log appender?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to send an eMail when the connection between WebSphere and MQ is lost.

But you can configure WebSphere to try to reestablish the lost connection. You can configure the number of reconnect retries as well as the time interval between two retries.
With the default configuration WebSphere stops retries to reestablish a lost connection after a relative short time. I asume between 20 to 30 minutes.

If you use a listener port to connect your MDB to MQ you have to set properties of the listener port service. Search for MAX.RECOVERY.RETRIES and RECOVERY.RETRY.INTERVAL in online WebSphere documentation.

If you use an activation specification you have to configure the properties of the built-in MQ Resource adapter. This is a tricky thing, as this resource adapter is not displayed in WebSphere amdin console per default. Open WebSphere Admin console > Resource > Resource adapter and open the preferences. There you have to click the checkbox "show built-in resource adapter" and then "Apply". You can find the recovery settings for lost connections in the MQ Resource adapter's custom properties. Be sure you select the adapter with the same scope as your activation specification.

Hope that hepls.